# Carrierwave Cannot update a database to correct value after calling recreate_versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I am trying to reprocess all image uploads in my Rails app which uses Carrierwave as I have added a new image version. Looking at the documentation and other examples I found online I created a rake file with the following code:

```
namespace :reprocess_user_photo do
    desc "RESIZE"
    task :recreate => :environment do
        User.all.each do |user|
            if user.photo?
                puts user.photo_url
                user.photo.cache_stored_file!
                user.photo.retrieve_from_cache!(user.photo.cache_name)
                user.photo.recreate_versions!
                puts user.photo_identifier
                user.update_column(:photo, File.basename(user.photo_url))
                user.save!
                puts user.photo_identifier
            end
        rescue => e
            puts  "ERROR: User: #{user.id} -> #{e.to_s}"
        end
    end
end
```

This has the output of the following:

```
/uploads/user/photo/2/1f99e6711141ef7ee2a516db9a197e87.jpg
1f99e6711141ef7ee2a516db9a197e87.jpg
9fda01d5a01ab9803d08d108078345bf.jpg
```

From this I can see the file being reprocessed is the correct one. The new file has a new name and appears in the correct directory (the new file can be found there) but the update to the database is not the correct file (this file name relates to an old file that existed before I started working on this feature and has long since been deleted).

I have also tried replacing this code with:

```
namespace :reprocess_user_photo do
    desc "RESIZE"
    task :recreate => :environment do
        User.all.each do |user|
            if user.photo?
                puts user.photo_url
                user.photo.cache_stored_file!
                user.photo.retrieve_from_cache!(user.photo.cache_name)
                user.photo.recreate_versions!
                puts user.photo_identifier
                user.photo = File.basename(user.photo_url)
                user.save!
                puts user.photo_identifier
            end
        rescue => e
            puts  "ERROR: User: #{user.id} -> #{e.to_s}"
        end
    end
end
```

which has the output:

```
/uploads/user/photo/2/0401399fd5c9092d5388e97b1991a295.jpg
0401399fd5c9092d5388e97b1991a295.jpg
0401399fd5c9092d5388e97b1991a295.jpg
```

This code does not replace the image at all.

Finally I have tried the following:

```
namespace :reprocess_user_photo do
    desc "RESIZE"
    task :recreate => :environment do
        User.all.each do |user|
            if user.photo?
                puts user.photo_url
                user.photo.cache_stored_file!
                user.photo.retrieve_from_cache!(user.photo.cache_name)
                user.photo.recreate_versions!
                puts user.photo_identifier
                user.save!
                puts user.photo_identifier
            end
        rescue => e
            puts  "ERROR: User: #{user.id} -> #{e.to_s}"
        end
    end
end
```

which has the output

```
/uploads/user/photo/2/946283bd082efbf970784d3c2c00235c.jpg
946283bd082efbf970784d3c2c00235c.jpg
9fda01d5a01ab9803d08d108078345bf.jpg
```

In this test the new image was created with the file name 5f41bc1e46c67e551e9ea36a8109bae2.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After another day or so of trying to fix my problem I have a solution that kind of works. This is using the following code:

```
def self.reprocess_user_picture
    User.all.each do |user|
        if user.photo?
            user.photo.recreate_versions!
            user.update_column(:photo, File.basename(user.photo.url))
        end
    end
end
```

This solution will reprocess all image uploads for the user photo in all versions. It however will not delete the old versions but at least the database is updated correctly.

Now, I know this solution is not perfect. If someone wants to try and answer the original please do and I will try out the solution. The reason why I was struggling with other attempts (and why an old image name was appearing back in the database) is still not clear but I can only think it is some kind of caching that I could not figure out.